# Maven ignores execution configuration

Tags: maven, jax-ws

I'm trying to have two execution blocks inside a maven plugin with separate configurations, but maven seems to ignore the configuration blocks inside the execution blocks and only uses the configuration block outside the executions block.

So to narrow down the problem, I took a working plugin section and moved the working configuration just slightly up towards the inside of the execution block and then it stopped working (the wsdl is still being picked up (actually both are), but that's simply because it's sitting in the default directory, the binding file and non of the other configuration is being picked up when the configuration section is sitting inside the execution block and in fact, it should not even be aware of the second wsdl since I haven't specified it anywhere):

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin> 
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId> 
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
                <version>2.1</version> 
                <executions>
                    <execution> 
                        <id>wsdla</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration> 
                            <packageName>com.mycee.project.model</packageName> 
                            <sourceDestDir>src/main/java</sourceDestDir>
                            <wsdlFiles>
                                <wsdlFile>
                                  ${basedir}/src/wsdl/a.wsdl
                                </wsdlFile>            
                            </wsdlFiles>
                            <bindingDirectory>
                                ${basedir}/src/wsdl/binding
                            </bindingDirectory>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals> 
                            <goal>wsimport</goal> 
                        </goals>            
                    </execution> 
                </executions>
            </plugin> 
        </plugins>  
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Is this a maven issue I need to resolve or a jaxws issue and how do I resolve this?

If I change the version to 2.3, I get the following error:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.3:wsimport (default-cli) on project mycee-project: Execution default-cli of goal org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.3:wsimport failed: String index out of range: -1 -> [Help 1]

running mvn clean jaxws:wsimport -X
I can see in the debug output that it's using the defaults:

```
[DEBUG] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Goal:          org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.3:wsimport (default-cli)
[DEBUG] Style:         Regular
[DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <bindingDirectory default-value="${basedir}/src/jaxws"/>
  <destDir default-value="${project.build.outputDirectory}"/>
  <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
  <extension default-value="false"/>
  <genJWS default-value="false"/>
  <implDestDir default-value="${project.build.sourceDirectory}"/>
  <keep default-value="true"/>
  <localRepository default-value="${localRepository}"/>
  <pluginArtifactMap>${plugin.artifactMap}</pluginArtifactMap>
  <quiet default-value="false"/>
  <remoteRepositories default-value="${project.pluginArtifactRepositories}"/>
  <settings>${settings}</settings>
  <sourceDestDir default-value="${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/wsimport"/>
  <staleFile default-value="${project.build.directory}/jaxws/stale"/>
  <verbose default-value="false"/>
  <wsdlDirectory default-value="${basedir}/src/wsdl"/>
  <xadditionalHeaders default-value="false"/>
  <xdebug default-value="false"/>
  <xdisableAuthenticator default-value="false"/>
  <xdisableSSLHostnameVerification default-value="false"/>
  <xnoAddressingDataBinding default-value="false"/>
  <xnocompile default-value="true"/>
  <xuseBaseResourceAndURLToLoadWSDL default-value="false"/>
  <project default-value="${project}"/>
</configuration>
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
```

The debug output for the index out of range error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.3:wsimport (default-cli) on project mycee-project: Execution default-cli of goal org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.3:wsimport failed: String index out of range: -1 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.3:wsimport (default-cli) on project mycee-project: Execution default-cli of goal org.jvnet.jax-ws-c
ommons:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.3:wsimport failed: String index out of range: -1
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:225)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-cli of goal org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.3:wsimport failed: String index out of range: -1
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:110)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.substring(AbstractStringBuilder.java:872)
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.substring(StringBuilder.java:72)
        at org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.jaxws.AbstractJaxwsMojo.getCP(AbstractJaxwsMojo.java:484)
        at org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.jaxws.AbstractJaxwsMojo.exec(AbstractJaxwsMojo.java:359)
        at org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.jaxws.WsImportMojo.processLocalWsdlFiles(WsImportMojo.java:319)
        at org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.jaxws.WsImportMojo.execute(WsImportMojo.java:283)
        at org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.jaxws.MainWsImportMojo.execute(MainWsImportMojo.java:50)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        ... 20 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

Full pom as requested:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mycee</groupId>
  <artifactId>mycee-project</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>mycee</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.2</slf4j.version>
  </properties>

  <repositories>

  </repositories>  
    <pluginRepositories>

    </pluginRepositories>  
  <dependencies>
    <!-- Junit4 Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.10</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>  

    <!-- XML Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
        <artifactId>webservices-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Log Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
      <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin> 
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId> 
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
                <version>2.1</version> 
                <executions>
                    <execution> 
                        <id>basic</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration> 
                            <packageName>com.mycee.project.model</packageName> 
                            <sourceDestDir>src/main/java</sourceDestDir>
                            <wsdlFiles>
                                <wsdlFile>
                                  ${basedir}/src/wsdl/wsdla.wsdl
                                </wsdlFile>            
                            </wsdlFiles>
                            <bindingDirectory>
                                ${basedir}/src/jaxws/binding
                            </bindingDirectory>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                            <target>2.1</target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals> 
                            <goal>wsimport</goal> 
                        </goals>            
                    </execution> 
                </executions>
            </plugin> 
        </plugins>  
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>


</project>
```

Comment: full pom added as requested. I've added <target>2.1</target> to the jaxws configuration, that seems to get rid of the maven error, but still doesn't resolve the problem of the config not getting picked up when inside the execution block.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your pom should look like this:

```
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin> 
        <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId> 
        <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
        <version>2.1</version> 
      </plugin> 
    </plugins>  
  </pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin> 
      <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId> 
      <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
      <executions>
        <execution> 
          <id>basic</id>
          <phase>generate-sources</phase>
          <goals> 
            <goal>wsimport</goal> 
          </goals>            
          <configuration> 
            <packageName>com.mycee.project.model</packageName> 
            <wsdlFiles>
              <wsdlFile>${basedir}/src/wsdl/wsdla.wsdl</wsdlFile>            
            </wsdlFiles>
            <bindingDirectory>${basedir}/src/jaxws/binding</bindingDirectory>
            <verbose>true</verbose>
            <target>2.1</target>
          </configuration>
        </execution> 
      </executions>
    </plugin> 
  </plugins>    
</build>
```

The problem is based on that you do all stuff in the pluginManagement block and not in build block which means it's not really executed.

Comment: After I made it like you said, it was still not working until I changed bindingDirectory to bindingFiles. You are my hero :-)
Thanks for teaching me this valuable maven tip!!

Answer (score 4):

The above point is correct but your maven is ignoring configuration because you have it inside of the *execution* node. Move it into the *plugin* node and configuration should work (e.g. below)

```
<plugin> 
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId> 
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
    <version>2.1</version> 
    <executions>
        <execution> 
            <id>wsdla</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <!--
            if you have one more than one execution node put your configuration here
            -->
            <goals> 
                <goal>wsimport</goal> 
            </goals>            
        </execution> 
    </executions>
    <configuration> 
        <packageName>com.mycee.project.model</packageName> 
        <sourceDestDir>src/main/java</sourceDestDir>
        <wsdlFiles>
            <wsdlFile>
                ${basedir}/src/wsdl/a.wsdl
            </wsdlFile>            
        </wsdlFiles>
        <bindingDirectory>
            ${basedir}/src/wsdl/binding
        </bindingDirectory>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I had same problem which used to work when i had more than one execution node. After i used same client in other project the configuration seemed to be ignored.

So to keep long story short: if you have one execution node keep the configuration outside otherwise keep it inside.

Comment: What's the point of several executions if configuration will be the same?

Comment: You kind of have a point - but according to documentation the configuration should be inside of "execution" node.

Comment: configuration inside execution is allowed since maven 3.3.1 https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/release-notes.html

Answer (score -1):

[Error failed to execute goal org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgH85.png)

How to Fix

go pom.xml file > find Plugin (org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons) > select version 2.3.1-b201500201.1248

[How to fix the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNi0p.png)

```
          <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1-b20150201.1248</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsimport</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <wsdlFiles>
                                <wsdlFile>localhost_8080/Soap-Service/CustomerService.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                            </wsdlFiles>
                            <packageName></packageName>
                            <vmArgs>
                                <vmArg>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</vmArg>
                            </vmArgs>
                            <wsdlLocation>http://localhost:8080/Soap-Service/CustomerService?wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                            <staleFile>${project.build.directory}/jaxws/stale/CustomerService.stale</staleFile>
                        </configuration>
                        <id>wsimport-generate-CustomerService</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
                        <artifactId>webservices-api</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <sourceDestDir>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/jaxws-wsimport</sourceDestDir>
                    <xnocompile>true</xnocompile>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <extension>true</extension>
                    <catalog>${basedir}/src/jax-ws-catalog.xml</catalog>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Please post that information as text, not image

Comment: Is this an answer or a question?