# How do I get Intellij IDEA to call wsimport when I build my project?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

In my pom file, I have this plugin:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>Generate Web Service Client</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsimport</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <keep>true</keep>
                        <extension>true</extension>
                        <catalog>App-models/catalog.xml</catalog>
                        <packageName>com.app.client</packageName>
                        <wsdlUrls>
                            <wsdlUrl>${basedir}/xml-resources/web-service-references/App/wsdl/App.wsdl</wsdlUrl>
                        </wsdlUrls>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

This works exactly like it's supposed to if I run `mvn compile`: It generates the client sources.  But, if I *build* in Intellij IDEA, it seems to skip this plugin/step.  In other words, it skips wsimport if I click this button:

[image: build button]

Since IDEA is importing all the other build settings from the pom file, why not this one?

My work around is to manually call `mvn compile` if I ever clean my project or change a web service, but it's pretty annoying that Intellij-IDEA isn't automatically doing this for me.  Is this a bug, or is there a setting I can turn on to make it do this step?

Comment: Do you have a maven button to the far right where you can invoke the different maven goals? Try that, I guess it should execute maven properly. I haven't used the latest version of IDEA, but that button looks more like a "refresh dependencies" one.

Comment: @Magnilex Yep.  The only advantage to running "compile" there is I don't have to tab out to a console.  I don't really consider this to be even a workaround.  I'm using the latest.

Comment: @DanielKaplan were you ever able to figure out why Idea would not run wsimport goal? I was having the same issue. What helped me was moving the configuration block outside the executions block. More here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22282474/399435

Comment: @KarthicRaghupathi thanks for the tip.  Unfortunately I'm not working at the same company.  it will take me a lot of effort to try and reproduce this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose to execute any module's lifecycle phases and/or plugin-goals before and/or after make, rebuild, and/or run/debug. Right click on the phase or goal in the maven tool window and select the option you want. You can choose multiple options (one at a time). In your case you can choose the plug-in in the module/project and right click on the wsimport goal and choose to run before make.

[image]

Comment: Wow that's interesting, but there seems to be a problem.  When I do this on the plugin it runs and gives this message: `[INFO] No WSDLs are found to process, Specify atleast one of the following parameters: wsdlFiles, wsdlDirectory or wsdlUrls.`  So it seems like it's not using the configuration of the pom.xml file.  If I run `mvn compile` this doesn't show up.  Is there any way to pass the configuration in?  Otherwise I can't really use this.  I could run `compile` every time, but I think that'd really slow my build time.

Comment: Something else is wrong. Probably your maven configuration in IntelliJ. Check that it is configured to use the same maven version and settings files as your command line.