# Maven+Eclipse compilation fails, Maven compilation on terminal works

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am having a problem when trying to compile a Maven project from inside Eclipse Mars (4.5.1).

Specs:

- Win 7 SP1 x64
- JDK x64 1.8.0_72
- Eclipse x64 4.5.1
- Maven 3.3.9

I believe this to be an Eclipse-Maven plugin interaction problem, as I am able to execute goals from the terminal such as:

```
mvn clean compile

mvn generate-sources

mvn install
```

In Eclipse, when I right-click on the project name and chose **Maven install** as the goal to execute, I get the following errors:

> Scanning for projects
>
> ...
>
> Building project-name-1.0-SNAPSHOT ...
>
> [WARNING] The POM for com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-rt:jar:2.2.10 is invalid,
>   transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug
>   logging for more details
>
> [INFO] --- jaxws-maven-plugin:2.3:wsimport (default) @ project-name
>
> [WARNING] The POM for com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-tools:jar:2.2.10 is
>   invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available,
>   enable debug logging for more details
>
> [INFO] Processing:
>   file:/C:/project-name/src/main/resources/file.wsdl [INFO]
>   jaxws:wsimport args: [-keep, -s,
>   C:\project-name\target\generated-sources\wsimport, -d,
>   C:\project-name\target\classes, -encoding, UTF-8, -Xnocompile,
>   "file:/C:/project-name/src/main/resources/file.wsdl"]
>
> [WARNING] Failed to build parent project for
>   com.sun.xml.ws:bundles:pom:2.2.10
>
> [WARNING] Failed to build parent project for
>   com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-tools:pom:2.2.10
>
> [WARNING] Invalid POM for
>   com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-tools:jar:2.2.10, transitive dependencies (if
>   any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
>
> [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
>
> ...
>
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.3:wsimport (default) on
>   project project-name: Execution default of goal
>   org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.3:wsimport failed:
>   String index out of range: -1 -> [Help 1]
>
> [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with
>   the -e switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full
>   debug logging. [ERROR] [ERROR] For more information about the errors
>   and possible solutions, please read the following articles: [ERROR]
>   [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException

However, if I execute `mvn install` from the terminal, the goal is successful!
I think I have all the necessary Maven plugins installed in Eclipse and the pom.xml file is correct, as via the terminal everything seems to work.
Hoping that someone will be able to hint into this problem.

EDIT: while `mvn install` fails in Eclipse, if I create a Maven Build configuration in Eclipse with goal `mvn install -e`, the problem does not happen. Passing this flag is somehow solving this problem.

EDIT: I paste the specific pom.xml section which triggers the problem in Eclipse (bold text is what Eclipse underlines in red):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <!-- http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Quick_Overview -->

    <groupId>group.name</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-name</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>${project.artifactId}</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

        <wsdl.directory>${basedir}/../project-dep/src/main/resources</wsdl.directory>
        <wsdl.filename>file.wsdl</wsdl.filename>

        <mainclass>group.name.subname.TestApplication</mainclass>

        <ws.url>http://localhost:8081/sample-ws/endpoint</ws.url>

        <ws.name>Sample</ws.name>
        <uddi.url>http://localhost:9090</uddi.url>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- JAX-WS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- UDDI -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>group.name.uddi</groupId>
            <artifactId>uddi-naming</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- SOAP Handlers -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>group.name.soap</groupId>
            <artifactId>ws-handlers</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JMockit - must appear before JUnit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jmockit</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
            <version>1.21</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JUnit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsimport</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- https://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/wsimport-mojo.html -->
                    <wsdlDirectory>${wsdl.directory}</wsdlDirectory>
                    <wsdlFiles>
                        <wsdlFile>${wsdl.filename}</wsdlFile>
                    </wsdlFiles>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxws-tools</artifactId>
                        <version>2.2.10</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- to prevent deprecation warning: -->
                    <killAfter>-1</killAfter>
                    <mainClass>${mainclass}</mainClass>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>${ws.url}</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>assemble</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <programs>
                        <program>
                            <mainClass>${mainclass}</mainClass>
                            <id>${project.artifactId}</id>
                        </program>
                    </programs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

This is my Maven installation inside Eclipse:

[image]

Comment: did you try `mvn clean compile` from `Eclipse`?

Comment: Is your settings.xml in eclipse are the same as the one used in command-line?

Comment: Yes I have tried that **mvn clean compile** sequence, also with "Maven update" in between. @drgn what do you mean? When I execute Maven via the terminal, the only file it uses is the pom.xml, from what I know...

Comment: It also use your settings.xml in ~/.m2/settings.xml and need to be imported to eclipse into the preferences menu. (Utimately, it also use the settings.xml in the apache maven installation)

Comment: @drgn I will lookg into that. As additional information, if I run `mvn install` in Eclipse it fails with the aforementioned error, but if I create a build configuration in Eclipse for Maven with `mvn install -e` for debugging, the error does not happen.

Comment: @mcoimbra This makes the bug even weirder :)

Comment: The question here, I think, is the following error: " org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.3:wsimport failed: String index out of range: -1 "

What could be triggering this error inside Eclipse when it does happen outside?

Any hypothesis?

Comment: Did you check that Eclipse uses your version of maven and not the embdded one ?

Comment: @Hohenheim how would I go about checking that?

Comment: `Windows -> Préférences -> Maven -> Installations` @mcoimbra

Comment: so you found the embdded version or not ? @mcoimbra

Comment: @Hohenheim: I added an image at the end of the original post. It shows the version in use. It was already specified to be my custom version...

Comment: @mcoimbra i check your `pom.xml` and it's a little bit weird. you have to close `</plugins>`. and the plugins is Under `<build>` and the dependency `<dependency>`is Under `<dependencies></dependencies>` out of the build.

Comment: I agree with @Hohenheim. Can you show the complete pom?

Comment: Added the complete pom.xml. Masked some package names, but the structure is identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check in `Maven > User Settings` that `User Settings` points to the same archive than your Maven.

Did you try with the EMBBEDED one?

Comment: This did the trick. This triggered an internal refresh in Eclipse and it now works. Switching to `EMBEDDED` and then back to my personal installation did it.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, if it works fine in the console, you have a project that be can importe in every IDE's who support Maven projects. It's a good news.

Secondly, check if the selected **maven profile** (repository configuration,...) is the same in console and in Eclipse.

Then you could check your configuration in the **settings.xml** (in your .m2 directory)

Maybe this previous answer could help too:
[Maven ignores execution configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17695673/maven-ignores-execution-configuration)

Comment: Unfortunately, it is a problem pertaining Eclipse. In the terminal, Maven is behaving as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you the specifics, but I've seen both cases where Eclipse works/cmdline doesn't and vice-versa, in particular with complicated generics and deeply-nested interfaces.

To me it appears that Eclipse is doing some of its own parsing/byte-code generation, perhaps using tools.jar underneath the sheets, but I've never dug deep enough (especially since I prefer IntelliJ, which uses native maven and JVM and doesn't have this problem).

Ultimately, you can't trust Eclipse, the only way to know for sure is cmdline generation (as you've experienced).

Comment: Please check the original question's bottom edit, I think it is in line with what you wrote. What would you suggest to investigate deeper?

Comment: Ditch Eclipse.  Sorry, but it's a swiss army knife with many, many blades, and some of them don't work very well.  I've had problems with maven, java compilation, and git integration and steer everyone I can away from it.

Comment: I understand your suggestion. However, Eclipse is mandatory at the moment. Scott, would you have any additional suggestion to start digging into the Eclipse execution stack to try and understand what it is not being read properly from the Maven configuration?

Comment: Dig all you want, sometimes the problem can be resolved but other times it can't.  Update the Eclipse plugins, upgrade Eclipse, downgrade Eclipse, etc., something might work but if you're stuck on Eclipse, bad gig.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have to reorganize your `pom.xml` :

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
   <artifactId>jaxws-tools</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.10</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

is in the `<build></build>` which is false. Also with the error we can see that the problem is :

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.3:wsimport

So he didn't understand the `<goal>` here dont know if . And btw in the end of plugins you have to add an **S** to `<plugins>`:

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsimport</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- https://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/wsimport-mojo.html -->
                    <wsdlDirectory>${wsdl.directory}</wsdlDirectory>
                    <wsdlFiles>
                        <wsdlFile>${wsdl.filename}</wsdlFile>
                    </wsdlFiles>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxws-tools</artifactId>
                        <version>2.2.10</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <pluginS>
```

I worked with a `jaxws-maven-plugin` before but with another name of `<groupId>` like this :

```
 <build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.12</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsimport</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <wsdlLocation>http://mysite/firstwsdl.asmx?wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                            <packageName>com</packageName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Try this and hope that will help.

Comment: Hohenheim, I appreciate your suggestions but I cannot comprehend some of them:

- The <plugins></plugins> tag in my pom.xml had no missing 's' character. And as per the official Maven documentation, there can be <dependencies> inside <plugin>: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_dependencies_Tag

- The JAX-WS Maven plugin moved from the codehaus mojo project but as of 2007 it moved to jax-wx-commons (https://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/), hence the difference in the <groupId>...</groupId> tag.

Comment: Furthermore, this pom.xml executes perfectly with `mvn install` in the terminal, it is an Eclipse-specific Maven interaction problem.