# jaxws-maven-plugin multiple executions not working

Tags: java, maven, jax-ws, jaxws-maven-plugin

I'd like to generate java classes for multiple WSDLs. Due to name conflicts in the different schemas, each WSDL should be in one java package. I created the following executions in my pom.xml:

```
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>service1</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>wsimport</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <wsdlUrls>
              <wsdlUrl>http://myserver/service1?wsdl</wsdlUrl>
            </wsdlUrls>
            <keep>false</keep>
            <sourceDestDir>target/generatedclasses</sourceDestDir>
            <packageName>com.myservice1</packageName>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
          <id>service2</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>wsimport</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <wsdlUrls>
              <wsdlUrl>http://myserver/service2?wsdl</wsdlUrl>
            </wsdlUrls>
            <keep>false</keep>
            <sourceDestDir>target/generatedclasses</sourceDestDir>
            <packageName>com.myservice2</packageName>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

But obviously the WSDL location can not be found:

```
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.codehaus.mojo:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.5:wsimport from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.5, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.codehaus.mojo:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.5:wsimport' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) bindingDirectory = C:\sandbox\ws-client\src\jaxws
[DEBUG]   (f) destDir = C:\sandbox\ws-client\target\classes
[DEBUG]   (f) extension = false
[DEBUG]   (f) genJWS = false
[DEBUG]   (f) implDestDir = C:\sandbox\ws-client\src\main\java
[DEBUG]   (f) keep = true
[DEBUG]   (f) pluginDescriptor = Component Descriptor: role: 'org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo', implementation: 'org.codehaus.mojo.jaxws.HelpMojo', role hint: 'org.codehaus.mojo:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.5:help'
role: 'org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo', implementation: 'org.codehaus.mojo.jaxws.MainWsGenMojo', role hint: 'org.codehaus.mojo:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.5:wsgen'
role: 'org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo', implementation: 'org.codehaus.mojo.jaxws.TestWsGenMojo', role hint: 'org.codehaus.mojo:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.5:wsgen-test'
role: 'org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo', implementation: 'org.codehaus.mojo.jaxws.MainWsImportMojo', role hint: 'org.codehaus.mojo:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.5:wsimport'
role: 'org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo', implementation: 'org.codehaus.mojo.jaxws.TestWsImportMojo', role hint: 'org.codehaus.mojo:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.5:wsimport-test'
---
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: org.example:wsclient:1.0-SNAPSHOT @ C:\sandbox\ws-client\pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) quiet = false
[DEBUG]   (f) session = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@22680f52
[DEBUG]   (f) settings = org.apache.maven.execution.SettingsAdapter@39c11e6c
[DEBUG]   (f) sourceDestDir = C:\sandbox\ws-client\target\generated-sources\wsimport
[DEBUG]   (f) staleFile = C:\sandbox\ws-client\target\jaxws\stale
[DEBUG]   (f) useJdkToolchainExecutable = false
[DEBUG]   (f) verbose = false
[DEBUG]   (f) wsdlDirectory = C:\sandbox\ws-client\src\wsdl
[DEBUG]   (f) xadditionalHeaders = false
[DEBUG]   (f) xdebug = false
[DEBUG]   (f) xdisableAuthenticator = false
[DEBUG]   (f) xdisableSSLHostnameVerification = false
[DEBUG]   (f) xnoAddressingDataBinding = false
[DEBUG]   (f) xnocompile = true
[DEBUG]   (f) xuseBaseResourceAndURLToLoadWSDL = false
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[DEBUG] The wsdl Directory is C:\sandbox\ws-client\src\wsdl
[INFO] No WSDLs are found to process, Specify at least one of the following parameters: wsdlFiles, wsdlDirectory or wsdlUrls.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.808 s
```

I don't understand, why this example isn't working. It seems that the configuration is valid (see [Multiple WSDLs Configurations With Maven JAXWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674456/multiple-wsdls-configurations-with-maven-jaxws))

If I move the `configuration` element two levels up it works! (But I can only configure one execution...)

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>wsimport</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
        <wsdlUrls>
          <wsdlUrl>http://myserver/service1?wsdl</wsdlUrl>
        </wsdlUrls>
        <keep>false</keep>
        <sourceDestDir>target/generatedclasses</sourceDestDir>
        <packageName>com.myservice1</packageName>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Any ideas for a solution are strongly appreciated!

(P.S. Java 8, Maven 3.6.2)

Comment: First thing that sticks out to me is that the execution in your logs should mention your execution id of the plugin and it seems like your logs aren't showing that.  Are you sure you captured the log from actual run with two executions?

Comment: @dsingleton yes, this is the actual log. But I don't see the execution id logged

Comment: Even when I try the example from the manufacturer page (https://www.mojohaus.org/jaxws-maven-plugin/examples/using-wsdlLocation.html). It will give me `No WSDLs are found to process, Specify at least one of the following parameters` Maybe it's the maven version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to run the "install" Lifecycle rather than the plugin jaxws:import directly.